# Run time error 462 Access VBA using Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I occasionally get a run time error when trying to open/manipulate Excel files using Access VBA. The error is

> "Run-Time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is
>   unavailable

What is frustrating is that the error occurs only for certain files and not others and in different instances. Here is my code, the error occurs at the `workbooks.open(sPath)` line:

```
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet

Set oExcel = Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(1)

oExcel.Visible = False

    If fGetFileName(sPath) = "FILE_NAME1.xlsx" Then
        'oExcel.Visible = False
        oWS.Range("AW1").Value = "TEXT1"
        oWS.Range("AX1").Value = "TEXT2"
        oWS.Range("AY1").Value = "TEXT3"
    End If

oWB.Save
Debug.Print "Amended " & sPath

oWB.Close False
Set oWB = Nothing

oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

After a bit of research online, I've found this document gives a good overview of the error: https://anictteacher.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/vba-error-462-explained-and-resolved.pdf

Using the logic from that document, the error is that:

> object has not been fully qualified by reference to the Office object
>   in every case

However, I amended the row where the error occurs to specifically reference the Excel object (Set oWB = **oExcel**.Workbooks.Open(sPath)). Have tried declaring the dimensions as Objects and put reference to oExcel in every mention of a workbook/sheet. Any ideas? Does sPath need to better qualified?

Comment: What is the value of *sPath* when you encounter that error at `Workbooks.Open(sPath)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare *oExcel* as a new `Excel.Application`:

```vb
Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
```

That means later in your code, `Set oExcel = Excel.Application` is not really useful ... because *oExcel* is already a reference to `Excel.Application`.  Add in a `MsgBox` to demonstrate what *oExcel* is at that point ...

```vb
MsgBox "TypeName(oExcel): " & TypeName(oExcel)
'Set oExcel = Excel.Application
```

Consider a different approach for your Excel object variable.  Test this stripped down procedure (the purpose is only to see whether it eliminates your current error):

```vb
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox "TypeName(oExcel): " & TypeName(oExcel)
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
MsgBox "TypeName(oExcel): " & TypeName(oExcel)
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
oWB.Close False
Set oWB = Nothing
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, do use WorkSheet and close this:

```
Set oWS = oWB.WorkSheets(1)
' snip.
oWB.Save
Set oWs = Nothing    
oWB.Close False
Set oWB = Nothing
```