# Run-time error re "remote server machine" on 2nd run

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have already reviewed a couple of similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940143/run-time-error-462), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030584/error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-when-working-with-word-via-e), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649425/run-time-error-462-access-vba-using-excel) (including referenced link) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631641/run-time-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable) in careful detail, and not found anything that helped.

My script starts in an Excel construction estimate and outputs a proposal draft in Word. The general structure of the program is in three parts:

1. It pulls the data from the active worksheet (lines 1-226), then
2. It queries the user for some final needed bits of info via a userform (lines 227-265), then
3. It opens a letterhead template in Word and dumps everything into it (lines 266-763).

The first time I run the script from the Excel estimate, it executes flawlessly, all the way through to saving the Word document. But if I *close* that generated Word document and click the "Draft proposal" button *again*, it gets to a very specific line, not far into the Word portion of the program, and gives me an error, every time. That error is,

> "Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable."

Here is the script, starting at the beginning of the Word portion. It breaks at the line where we give our "$TBD" price, right-justified, at the end of trailing dots.

I used a macro to generate this little block of code. I have attempted to fix this bug by simplifying the code here. I used to have unnecessary lines `wDoc.DefaultTabStop = InchesToPoints(0.5)` and `sel.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll` and it used to break at *those* lines, but I deleted both of them, and the program still breaks right at the same spot.

```
'open the Word document with the appropriate template, bind worksheet & doc together,
'activate the window (bring to front), and move cursor to the end of the document
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\Users\" & MyUserName & "\"
'The rest of the filepath is included here, but I'm omitting it for security purposes, ending in "Letterhead.dotm")
wApp.Visible = True
wApp.Activate

Dim sel As Word.Selection
Set sel = wDoc.Application.Selection

sel.EndKey (wdStory)

'create date and address block

sel.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="MMMM dd, yyyy", InsertAsField:=False
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeText Text:=ContactName
sel.TypeText Text:=Chr(11)
sel.Font.Bold = wdToggle
sel.TypeText Text:=GCName
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeText "Reference: " & vbTab
sel.TypeText Text:=JobName
sel.Font.Bold = wdToggle
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeParagraph

'create the introductory matter to the proposal
sel.TypeText "We are pleased to offer our proposal for the electrical portion of work " & _
    "at " & JobAddress & ". Work is based upon " & ArchitectName & " " & PlanType & _
    " drawings, dated " & PlansDated & "."
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeParagraph

'make the line of dots before TBD, copy-pasting from a macro
sel.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(6.67), Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight, _
    Leader:=wdTabLeaderDots 'This is the two-line statement where it breaks.
```

Oddly, if I delete the offending statement, it gets a little further but then breaks at another random line a little ways down, the ".NumberPosition" property definition within the myNLT With block:

```
'write the price line, and then erase the single-use tab stop we just set up
sel.Font.Bold = wdToggle
sel.TypeText "We will perform this work for" & vbTab & "$TBD"
sel.Font.Bold = wdToggle
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll

'introduce the itemized SOW
sel.Font.Bold = wdToggle
sel.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
sel.TypeText "Scope of work to include the following:"
sel.TypeParagraph
sel.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
sel.Font.Bold = wdToggle

'set up itemized list, copy-pasting from a macro, list starts at 1
'establish myNLT as the numbered list template
Dim myNLT As ListTemplate
Set myNLT = wApp.ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1)
With myNLT.ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1."
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25) 'If I delete the line indicated
'in the previous block of code, then this is the next place it breaks.
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .ResetOnHigher = 0
    .StartAt = 1
    .LinkedStyle = ""
End With
```

I have tried `On Error Resume Next` and I've tried even adding, as "Next," an `Application.Wait` for two seconds followed by a repetition of the `TabStops.Add`, but this does nothing but mess up my formatting.

I also tried changing `sel.ParagraphFormat.Tabstops.Add` to `Word.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add` - also didn't work.

Following a suggestion in comments also did not work: If I remove everything after `.Add`, I get

> Compile error: Argument not optional.

If I then add back in the first argument, `Position:=InchesToPoints(6.67)` and leave off `Alignment` and `Leader`, then the error comes back.

Comment: This one contains the information: [Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist when working with Word via Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030584/error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-when-working-with-word-via-e)

Comment: The problem is addressed in the post I linked to above, but you may not have recognized it. The line of code causing the problem contains a number of Word-specific *enumeration* values and `methods`, such as `InchesToPoints`, `wdAlignTabRight` and `wdTabLeaderDots`. Try putting `wApp.` in front of the first (and use `wApp` everywhere you've used `wDoc.Application` since you've already defined it). And try putting `Word.` in front of the other two. This way Excel VBA will know it's dealing with Word things, not Excel things which it's not able to find...

Comment: Hi Cindy, I saw those comments and I tried to implement them as best I could, but I'm confused as to how to do so in my specific context, which is why I posted in the first place. Would you mind please humoring me and give me some revised lines to try? For instance, putting `wApp.` in front of the first line you mention gets me `wApp.sel.` at the beginning, which prompts "Compile error: Method or data member not found." Please remember that I am an utter newbie. I have coded in VBA for exactly 3 working days. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: When you work with `Selection` instead of `Range` in Word, it can introduce a lot of unnecessary chaos. I recommend redefining everything, all the way up to the `ListTemplate` as a `Word.Range` and trying from there. If you get stuck, I can add an answer with a demonstration.

Comment: @jclasley That's not the problem causing the above error. Please do not post an answer that's irrelevant to the problem. Yes, the code could use some stream-lining, but this is not the place (question) to do so.

Comment: Andrew, I'm not able to reproduce the error with any reliability. With or without what I suggested in my comment. My first reaction on reading the error text was something quite different - something not covered in the links. "Remove server machine" problems often have to do with something being automated from "outside" not being correctly *released*. IOW the connection to the Word Application is being held open after the code finishes, so when you try to run it again it can't access `Word.Application` properly...

Comment: ... It's not clear whether we're seeing enough of your code, but of the code we can see, *at the end* you'd need to set each object to `Nothing` in the reverse order things were instantiated. So: `Set sel = Nothing : Set wDoc = Nothing ; Set wApp = Nothing`. See if that makes a difference. If it does and no one turns up an exact duplicate (I could find one when I looked) I can write up an Answer. But when you look at "good" code samples for automating Word you should see this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for revisiting my question, @CindyMeister. I have just added the releasing all 18 objects in my now 1315 lines of code at the end of my program, just before `End Sub`. I had high hopes this would fix it. It didn't.

Comment: A germane detail: If there are other instances of Word open, this error does not happen.

I also tried breaking it into a With block, & removing arguments 1 by 1. The error happened each time. I used the Locals window to check the properties of `sel.ParagraphFormat.TabStops` — these properties at the line prior to the break were identical in both runs.